# What significance does "cross-platform" have in an ASP.NET Core a web application?

Tags: asp.net, macos, visual-studio, virtual-machine, cross-platform

Aside from language syntax benefits like mvc tag helpers, or greater support for loosely coupled, abstracted patterns like dependency injection, what benefit does a cross-platform asp.net core web application have if the application runs inside a browser and not on an operating system?

I should point out that I would like to use Visual Studio for Mac.  All performance tuning techniques aside, I find the overall development experience to suffer when working with Visual Studio inside a Windows 10 virtual machine.

Comment: It means that you will be able to **host** your site in Windows, Mac or Linux

Comment: @kblok Thank you for the reply